# how to create key of admob native ads in android?

Tags: android, key, admob, ads, banner-ads

i want to integrate native ads of admob but problem is how to create native ads key because it provide banner and interstitial ads key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[**Avocarrot**](http://www.avocarrot.com/)  is an ad networking where it provides different types of native ads. Developers can customize the ads where to place and use it. For eg: if you need to place ads at second cell every 15 row, you can use like this..

```
 AvocarrotInstream myAd = new AvocarrotInstream(<yourListAdapter>);
  myAd.initWithKey( "<your API Key>" );
  myAd.setSandbox(true);
  myAd.setLogger(true ,"ALL"); 

// Populate with In-Stream ads
 myAd.loadAdForPlacement(this,  "<your Placement Name>" );
// Bind the adapter to your list view component
<yourListView>.setAdapter(myAd);// here you are integrating ads to listview
 myAd.setFrequency(2,15); // every 15 cells starting from the 2nd cell.
```

Here is [Documentation](https://app.avocarrot.com/#/docs/getting-started/android/list) it provides List ads and Feed ads.